# Converting workbook VBA module into a personal.xlsb causes read-only problems

Tags: vba, excel

I got my macro working a couple days back. Being the newbie that I am I was coding in the workbook-level and now I made it into a personal macro. When I run the exactly same code in other workbook as personal macro, I run into some issues. 1st issues I managed to fix with some better but not good enough reformatting:

```
With ThisWorkbook
        For k = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
            If .Sheets(k).Name = "reportdata" Then
                blnFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k
        If blnFound = False Then
            .Sheets.Add
            With ThisWorkbook
                .Name = "reportdata" 'this is where the problem is at the moment
            End With
        End If
    End With

    Set datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set reportsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("reportdata")
    reportsheet.Move After:=Worksheets(1)
```

What I want to create here is another sheet called reportdata. This sheet would not be created if it already exists.

I think my problem probably lies in the ThisWorkbook reference. My index in the for loop seems to be off so it might be working on something else than I intended. My intention is that the user of this macro has a workbook with data from another source that has a sheet with always the same name. So the use case is pretty static.

How do I make the references in this part of the code work on a "global" scale and not just workbook level?

Thank you in advance for any tips you can give me!

Comment: You are working with `ThisWorkbook` - that is the workbook where the code lives in. Probably you don't want to modify data of your *Personal* workbook. Try `ActiveWorkbook` instead if you want to access the workbook that's currently visible

Comment: Oh right, you are correct. However, this appears to not be the issue as I still run into the same read-only error.

Answer (score 2):

```
        With ThisWorkbook
            .Name = "reportdata" 'this is where the problem is at the moment
        End With
```

That block expands to ThisWorkbook.Name = "reportdata", but a workbook doesn't have a writable Name property - what you should be naming is the sheet you just added not the workbook.

Comment: Thank, I changed the Sheets.Add and With-structure to just Sheets.Add.Name and now there are no errors. `If blnFound = False Then .Sheets.Add.Name = "reportdata" End If`. Well the code still doesnt work outside of the workbook it was coded in but at least there is one obstacle less to make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you're trying to do by using Error handling instead of looping. Have a look at the following (You can also condense a few things whilst you're at it as well)

```
Dim reportsheet as worksheet, datasheet as worksheet

With ThisWorkbook
    ' You can test if the sheet exists by handling the error if it doesnt
    On Error Resume Next
    Set reportsheet = .Sheets("reportdata")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Test if worksheet exists and add if not
    If reportsheet Is Nothing Then
        Set reportsheet = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(1))
        reportsheet.Name = "reportdata"
    End If

    Set datasheet = .Worksheets(1)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
.Sheets(k).Name = "reportdata"
```

Right?

Plus for your info `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` are different. The former is the activated workbook while the latter is the workbook where the VBA code is written

Comment: Hmm I am not quite sure what you mean? I have `If .Sheets(k).Name = "reportdata" Then` in the If clause. I need to add only 1 sheet called "reportdata" IF it does NOT exist. So I am not trying to rename all the sheets in the workbook. Or I might be missing something and commenting on something irrelevant? But the point about `ActiveWorkbook` is very much true and I should fix that 1st (but it didn't solve my read-only issue).

Comment: No, I mean in the line where you said that u have a problem currently. Harassed has explained why that causes an issue

Comment: I changed it to `Sheets.Add.Name = "reportdata"` and just removed the with structure. Now there are no errors.